# How to vertically take off in VTOL aircraft?

Tags: battlefield-2, project-reality

In Project Reality BF2 there are [Harriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_AV-8B_Harrier_II) and [Opsreys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Boeing_V-22_Osprey) and maybe more VTOL aircraft.

**How do I properly do a vertical take off with these?**

I tried pressing the <kbd>S</kbd> key to start hovering and gain some height and then pressing <kbd>W</kbd> to generate forward thrust but it takes very long to get the thrust up and reach enough speed for the aircraft to start flying so that I loose a lot of height in this process and often simply crash.

I guess there must be a better way.

Comment: Have you tried hovering longer so you start at a higher altitude?

Comment: Yes, if I hover very long and gain a lot of height, I manage to get the thing flying, but I always loose a lot of that height when going over to vertical flight and it just feels like there should be a better way :-)...

Comment: I'd try generating forward thrust while you're hovering so you have some speed built up when you make the switch.  Or try tipping the nose forward so you move while you hover.  Generating some forward velocity should reduce the time to achieve flight.  In one of the Battlefield games, I launched VTOLs from carriers by just slamming the throttle and hoping for the best.  I think that was BF3 though.

Comment: Tipping the nose sounds like a good idea, I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: @sommerjj see my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Ospreys getting some height in hovering mode and then tipping the nose to get some speed and going over to horizontal flight (as suggested by @sommerjj) works really well. For the harriers not so much.

If found a guide at the [PR forums](http://www.realitymod.com/forum/f562-pr-falklands-general-discussion/115412-guide-harrier-vertical-takeoff.html) though. It states four steps to do a vertical take off:

1. Gain at least 120 m of height in vertical mode.
2. Open throttle to 100%
3. Point nose up (30 to 40 degrees). This is apparently the most important step.
4. Pull up hard as soon as you have horizontal speed.

This works rather well although it's probably not very realistic.